# How to write an action filter for all controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, attributes, action-filter

Here is a sample action filter. We know that when we write an action filter then we need to decorate the controller with an attribute like this, to use  it for any controller.

I like to know whether there is any way to write an action filter which will work for all controllers in way that I do not need to decorate all the controllers with an action filter attribute. Any ideas?

```
[LogActionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{}

public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute

     {
          public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
          {
               Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
          }

          public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
          {
               Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
          }

          private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
          {
               var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
               var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
               var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName, controllerName, actionName);
               Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
          }

     }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public class LogActionFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);    
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);  
        }

        private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
        {
            var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
            var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", methodName, controllerName, actionName);
            Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
        }
    }

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LogActionFilterAttribute());
        }
    }
```

Comment: if we use GlobalFilters then my action filter will be invoked for all controller's action method?

Comment: yes, should implement IActionFilter. Actually, you can see the HandleErrorAttribute registered in FilterConfig.cs which is auto generated when you create an MVC application.

Comment: implement IActionFilter means? my all controller need to extend IActionFilter ?? not very clear what u try to do. if possible include a small complete code. thanks

Comment: thanks. my LogActionFilterAttribute extend this class ActionFilterAttribute but you extend IActionFilter why ?? what is the difference between ActionFilterAttribute & IActionFilter ? can guide me in details. thanks

Comment: ActionFilterAttribute also implements IActionFilter. So it's OK that you extend ActionFilterAttribute

Answer (score 4):

For your scenario you can just make a **Custom BaseController** and put your `[LogActionFilter]` attribute on **Custom Basecontroller** and inherit all your Controllers from **Custom Basecontroller** as shown below :

```
[LogActionFilter]
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{

}

public class MyOtherController : MyBaseController //<----instead of using Controller as base use MyBaseController as base class
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**The advantage of this approach is that you have to put your custom `[LogActionFilter]` attribute only at one place i.e. only on Custom BaseController.**

Comment: can u write bit of code to understand what u r trying to say. thanks

Comment: here i saw u decorate MyBaseController with LogActionFilter and again wrote OnActionExecuting() routine in basecontroller then how the LogActionFilter code would look like. in my question i wrote OnActionExecuting() routine in LogActionFilter class. do i need to repeat LogActionFilter code in 2 place ??

Comment: @Thomas...no..no you just have to decorate baseController with the attribute only and its done..

Comment: @Thomas...i have updated answer...i think you got confused there ...updated the answer..i just put a generalized answer so that other users with problem somewhat similar to your problem can also be benefitted from this answer.

Comment: just see the basecontroller code u wrote. ur basecontroller decorated with LogActionFilter but u wrote OnActionExecuting() inside in basecontroller. i guess LogActionFilter should have this routine OnActionExecuting() inside it.

Comment: @Thomas...yes i understand but it is the basic architecture of making your own basecontroller in your scenario you just put your attribute on basecontroller and its done.

Comment: You don't even need the attribute. If you have a `BaseController` from which your other controllers subclass, you can directly override `OnActionExecuting` and every other action filter method.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already subclassing from a base controller, you don't need a filter attribute or to register anything. You can just override the desired methods, e.g.,

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
      ViewBag.SomeValue = "glorp frob blizz nunk";
      // Access the controller, parameters, querystring, etc. from the filterContext
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
}
```

Then, every controller that subclasses from it will run that method:

```
public sealed class GlorpController : BaseController {
   public ActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

The view will quite happily see the `ViewBag.SomeValue` value.

Comment: Brilliant observation.  Certainly keeps things simpler.  As it turns out, this was my precise objective, to create a ViewBag variable for all Action Methods.  I guess I'll have to wait until I have a real need for a filter.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I would encourage you to think carefully about your use of `ViewBag`, specifically, how will your web app work when it is running on multiple servers running in different parts of the world, and each request from a particular client may or may not go to the same server? Even if your routing infrastructure (including load balancers) has affined a client to a particular server, there will always be edge cases. Just think about that carefully...

Comment: I thought that would be an issue so I appreciate your follow up comment and confirmation of my concern.  I haven't figured out how to avoid using ViewBag since the data supplied cuts across all action methods and the base controller isn't aware of method specific data.  But I did capture the data by user.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Alan it’s fine to do what you’re doing, don’t stop. My advice wasn’t a hard warning against ViewBag use. Just keep this in mind as you learn in your career and keep looking for those trade offs you have to manage. Read and study, find articles, and ask questions. That’s all!

Comment: How do I set the viewbag from within an OnActionExecuting filter?  That would allow selectivity for when to set the ViewBag by using an attribute.  But ViewBag is part of the Controller Class not accessible when the FilterAttribute Class is inherited.

Comment: At this point we've exceeded the ready knowledge I have of this. I'm sorry! It's been almost 3 years now since I last worked with this. My apologies if my answer misled you.

Comment: It's all good.  After some digging I found the path to ViewBag data through the FilterContext, which was an education of itself.  Thanks for pointing me down this road.