# ASP.NET MVC pass a parameter from a view to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a way to know what link was pressed when a controller was called.  My link is here in my view page:

```
<li id="tabFiles"><a href="~/Files" id="test">Files</a></li>
```

and my Files controller is here:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string submit)
    {
        string s = submit;

            return View();

    }
```

I tried to pass in a string hoping it would be the id of the clicked link, but this only returns a null.

Comment: why not use querystring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the id as query string:

```
<li id="tabFiles"><a href="~/Files/?id=test">Files</a></li>


public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    string s = id;
    return View();
}
```

Or you may want to pass that in this form:

```
<li id="tabFiles"><a href="~/Files/test">Files</a></li>
```

The way you send parameters to the controller depends on how you have configured [routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom action filter and set this on controller like this:

```
...
[CustomActionFilter]
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

and on this custom filter you can get action name like this:

```
public class 

CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)


    {
        // TODO: Add your acction filter's tasks here

        // Log Action Filter Call
        MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

        ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
        {
            Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName + " (Logged By: Custom 

Action Filter)",
            IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
            DateTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
        };

        storeDB.ActionLogs.Add(log);
        storeDB.SaveChanges();

        this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

More details you can find [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) on Microsoft site or on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033214/how-to-write-action-filter-for-all-controller) question.