# C# MVC Display in Visual Studio console methods and partials that have been called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Is it possible for C# MVC to display in Visual Studio methods and partial views that have been used to render a specific page.

In Ruby on Rails, it looks like this:

[image: Ruby on Rails console]

[Image Source](http://www.rubyonrails365.com/7-must-have-gems-to-install-on-any-project/)

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify the web technologies in use.  We can't guess.  Are you using MVC?  Nancy?  Something else?

Comment: @Amy, C# MVC. Sorry missed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you will need to attach some event handlers to the view engine.  In order to do *that*, you need to replace or decorate the view engine.  We will do this using the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
public class TracingViewEngine : IViewEngine 
{ 
    private readonly IViewEngine _innerViewEngine;

    public TracingViewEngine(IViewEngine innerViewEngine) 
    { 
        _innerViewEngine = innerViewEngine; 
    }

    public ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, 
         bool useCache) 
    { 
        var result = _innerViewEngine.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache); 
        return CreateTracingViewEngineResult(result, partialViewName); 
    }

    public ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, 
        bool useCache) 
    { 
         var result = _innerViewEngine.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache); 
        return CreateTracingViewEngineResult(result, viewName); 
    }

    public void ReleaseView(ControllerContext controllerContext, IView view) 
     { 
        TracingView tracingView = (TracingView)view; 
        _innerViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, tracingView.InnerView); 
    }

    public ViewEngineResult CreateTracingViewEngineResult(ViewEngineResult result, string name) 
    { 
        if (result.View == null) 
        { 
             return result; // no view to wrap 
        } 
         return new ViewEngineResult(new TracingView(result.View, name), this); 
    } 
}
```

All the class above does is give a decorated, tracing view to MVC upon request.  MVC wants to render something, it requests a view from your engine, and your engine gives it a special "tracing" view, implemented below:

```
public class TracingView : IView 
{ 
    private readonly string _name; 
    public IView InnerView { get; private set; }

    public TracingView(IView innerView, string name) 
    { 
        InnerView = innerView; 
        _name = name; 
    }

    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) 
    { 
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("View {0} - rendering...", _name)); 
        InnerView.Render(viewContext, writer); 
        stopwatch.Stop(); 
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("View {0} - rendered: {1} ms", _name, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)); 
    } 
}
```

Note the code inside `Render`, just above this comment.  Feel free to replace the `Trace....` lines with however you wish to the logging.

The view decorator is simple enough that it doesn't require much in the way of explanation.  It does the rendering.

Finally, to make MVC pay attention to our new view engine, in your MVC setup code, you need to either:

- remove the existing view engines, and replace them with yours, OR
- simply wrap each existing view engine

The following code brings this together by wrapping the existing engines (we did, after all, implement this using the Decorator pattern):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ViewEngines.Engines.Count; i++) 
{ 
    ViewEngines.Engines[i] = new TracingViewEngine(ViewEngines.Engines[i]); 
}
```

This will give you output like the following:

> View Index - rendering...
>   View _LoginPartial - rendering...
>   View _LoginPartial - rendered: 0 ms
>   View _Featured - rendering...
>   View _Featured - rendered: 0 ms
>   View Index - rendered: 6 ms

Credit for this answer goes to [Stewart Leeks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2013/11/15/understanding-view-rendering-performance-in-asp-net-mvc/).  I just added some extra explanation and cleaned up the code a tad.

Comment: THANKS! Is it possible to print the call stack of all methods that have been used as well?

Comment: *All* methods?  Not really.  Well, it's *possible*, but very invasive and very difficult, and only really possible with `virtual` methods.  You'd have to implement an interceptor, perhaps using DynamicProxy2.

Comment: A more reasonable thing to try would be to implement MiniProfiler.  It's pretty easy, has good instructions, and was written by the good folks at Stack Overflow.  I would recommend looking into that.  I didn't give this answer first because you'll need to track each method manually.  Check out the website and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Just to display control method that returned the view?

Comment: The controller action method is much more doable.  Implement an MVC action filter.  It isn't hard.

Comment: @KazKazar See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033214/how-to-write-an-action-filter-for-all-controllers) for details on making an action filter.  Just modify the code there to log to the same location as your view code and you're golden.

Comment: THANKS @Amy! hope it will be useful for other people as well