# How to redirect to a page from async method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to an error page like "https://www.mydomain/Timeout" when the API is taking longer to response (e.g., 60seconds).

The logic of getting the response from the API is written in the async method present in the ServiceLayer project in the same VS solution.

That async method is being called in the non-asynchronous controller (Present in the Web project in same VS solution).

When I check the time in async method and on the basis of that I do Response.Redirect in controller then it works. But, I want to do this in the async method because this is the method which is being called by around 50 APIs. So rather doing the Response.Redirect in each controller I want to handle it from here so that it will be applicable for each API.

Now please help me how to do it?

1. I tried to put the Response.Redirect("https://www.mydomain/timeout") in async method but that is not working.
2. I also tried Server.Transfer but no luck. Is this due to async method.

Below is the code of getting response from API which is written in async method.

```
private async Task<T1> PostA<T1,T2>(string method, T2 request, string api,
            bool isPut)
{
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();

        var response = isPut ? 
               await client.PutAsync(parturl, 
                 body).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false) :
               await client.PostAsync(parturl, 
                 body).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

  sw.Stop();

  long elapsedTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  if (elapsedTime >= 60000)
  {
     Response.Redirect("https://www.mydomain/timeout")
  }
}
```

In the method I have shown you only the required code, the rest of the logic has been removed.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that because this is against some of the MVC tenets, especially you are breaking the Separation of Concerns concept. The core principle is that only the `Controllers` should return `Views`, not your async method present in the ServiceLayer. You can either In your method return a Boolean result, and then in the controller, you can take the appropriate action.
OR: You can throw an exception in your method and the controller handles it redirecting to the appropriate view.

Comment: As @RahulSharma said, do the redirects from your controller, not the service layer.  The service layer should have no knowledge or concern whatsoever of the the UI that's placed on top of it.

Comment: I was trying to do the same, but I needed the guidance if there is any other possible way or not. Thanks all for the reply.

Comment: @RahulSharma. In this case, can you suggest me what can be the best approach to handle this case? I don't want each controller to receive the flag, set by API method, and do redirect. Suppose I want to create controllers in a new project from starting then how will you suggest to do it so that I can create the logic for each controller so that they can be redirected to "timeout" page if API is taking a long time to respond.

Comment: Can anyone let me know the answer for my previous comment?

Comment: @PrashantTomar You would have to create an action filter for this requirement. Specifcally the `onActionExecuting`. You can refer to this answer on how to create your own filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033214/how-to-write-an-action-filter-for-all-controllers

Comment: @PrashantTomar I also wanted to give you a better way in which you are finding your response time. You can do something like this: `var response = isPut ? await client.PutAsync(parturl,body).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false):await client.PostAsync(parturl,body).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false); if (await Task.WhenAny(response , Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))) == response ){//Got response before 60 seconds. Do something } else {//redirect here} `

Comment: @RahulSharma in the else {} part,  you mean I have to send some boolean flag to my controller. Because this method is present in the service layer project and this method is being called in the controller, which is in "myprojectname.web" project

Comment: Because redirection from async method  which is in service layer project is not happening, and it is against the MVC tenet, as you suggested

Comment: @PrashantTomar Yes you can do that to notify your controller what is required to be displayed. If you create your own filter, then you can control how the controller or your action method will behave on an event.

Comment: okay, I will try that way! Thanks @RahulSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I followed the approach on the basis of the comments above:

1. I created a static dictionary as `Dictionary<string, bool> d= new Dictionary<string, bool>();` in the class where my API calling method is written e.g., `MyApiClass`
2. I put the code line `client.timeout` = [your time here in milliseconds]; for API sending the request.
3. When API is time out then it throws `TaskTimeoutException`, so I caught the exception and put the code in catch block as `d.Add("timeout", true);`
4. I created the custom action filter and applied the following code:

   ```
   public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
       {
           if(MyApiClass.d.ContainsKey("timeout") && d["timeout"])
           {
               throw new Exception();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. I applied the `[CustomActionFilter]` on the action.
6. when action is executed and enter the custom filter it throws Exception by checking the dictionary entry. Now, we have `Application_Error()` in **Global.asax.cs** that catches the exception.
7. In the `Application_Error()` we have written the code for redirect to the required page.

NOTE: In step 4 you can create your custom exception to provide more precise detail for logging.